# how to change the default length of getline

Tags: c, getline

I am trying to solve a problem and in the process I am entering the strings using getline as follows( part of my main function)

```
 size_t n1=0,n2=0;
  char *a=0, *b=0;   
 getline(&a,&n1,stdin);
 getline(&b,&n2,stdin);
```

but no matter what input I give the value of n1 and n2 always stored as 120 . How can I overcome this problem to store the exact size of string I input

Comment: From the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline) `If *lineptr is not null, the behavior is undefined if *lineptr is not a pointer that can be passed to free or if *n is less than the size of the allocated memory pointed to by *lineptr`.  `lineptr` in your case would be `a` or `b`.  You need to initialize them otherwise you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: reading the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) is a good start.

Comment: @G.M. thanks for pointing out I actually missed writing here but in my original code the *lineptr is initialized to null but still the size of n1 and n2 are 120

Comment: Q: If you want "the exact size of string I input" ... then why not simply read the return value of getline()???

Comment: @paulsm4 as far as I was taught n1 should store the exact count of the string which I give as input but no matter which string I give I get the same 120 as the size of strings

Comment: You can't change the default that `getline()` allocates.  If you want an exact-size buffer, use `strdup()` on the input.  Or pre-allocate a smaller size, and tell `getline()` what that is: `size_t n1 = 32; char *a0 = malloc(n1);`.  But `getline()` chooses a reasonable default that usually avoids reallocations while reading inputs — most lines are not longer than 120 (or 128 or 256 or whatever default `getline()` uses).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks , I have a doubt that I have used this notation several times before but I never got such error , previously it was storing the exact length of string I gave as input but why it fails now

Comment: It's not an error; it is the expected behaviour of `getline()`.  Maybe you were using a different implementation of `getline()`?  Maybe you were reading strings consistently larger than the minimum buffer size.  You should produce an MCVE reproducing the old behaviour and explain how your current code differed.  The specification for `getline()` ensures there is enough space to hold the current data, which means it may allocate more space than minimally necessary. This reduces the number of times it has to reallocate memory.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think I cant attach a screenshot but when the size of string huge  still its allocating size of  120

Comment: Screenshots are of limited value.  If you need it, look up my email address in my profile and send information to me.  Include the URL for the question.  And include the necessary information as plain text if at all possible — copy’n’paste the output rather than a screenshot.  Include the code, of course.

Comment: Q: "As far as I was taught n1 should store the exact count of the string which I give as input".  A: As you hopefully now realize, this is *INCORRECT*.  "n" is your buffer size (or an indicator that the system should malloc() the buffer), *NOT* "string size".  That's what the return value is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I overcome this problem to store the exact size of string I input

First, you should stop regarding this as a problem and regard it as normal behavior of `getline`. You should adapt to `getline` and not expect it to adapt to you.

`getline` allocates a reasonable amount of spaces to work with. Allocating a smaller amount of space could require `getline` to reallocate space more frequently as continuing input required larger and larger allocations. This would waste resources including energy and time.

The `n1` or `n2` passed to `getline` by way of the second parameter is set to the size of the allocated space, not the length of the input read, and there is no way for you to alter this short of changing the implementation of `getline`. `getline` does not put the length of the input in `n1` or `n2`.

To get the length of the input that was read, save the return value of `getline`:

```
size_t l1 = getline(&a, &n1, stdin);
size_t l2 = getline(&b, &n2, stdin);
```

If the allocated space is a great concern, use `realloc` to inform the memory management software that the excess space is not needed:

```
char *temp = realloc(a, n1 = l1+1);
if (!temp) a = temp;
temp = realloc(b, n2 = l2+1);
if (!temp) b = temp;
```

Some `realloc` implementations are likely to ignore attempts to reduce the allocated space, especially when the allocated size is small.

Comment: the use of return value of get line worked , Thanks . But I never occurred such errors even if I am using the same notation , why now ?

Comment: @user You may call it an error but it is not. If you check the wrong variables, you might get unexpected results. Expecting a specific result for `n1` is not backed by the specification.  The only thing to expect is "big enough". Any implementation may decide to behave different and also change between versions.